# Node spawn transforms arguments characters?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, spawn

This is how I am using function `spawn` from `node:child_process` package:

```js
const args = [
    'Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib',
    'jar ./DynamoDBLocal.jar',
    'inMemory'
]

const dynamodb = spawn('java', args, {cwd: './dynamodb_local'})
```

It looks like the path from the first argument, gets somehow changed along the way because stderr from this command logs this

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Djava.library.path=..DynamoDBLocal_lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Djava/library/path=//DynamoDBLocal_lib
```

It looks like the slash gets converted to a dot and vice-versa?

This command, when used normally in a shell, works as expected.

Edit: I am running this on macOS.

Comment: Oh my god. I never thought I would see a question that is correctly tagged with both `javascript` and `java`. Bravo

Comment: This is the same i thought when i chose the tags. "I don't belive I am tagging a question with javascript and java!"

Comment: You have a space in the second element of your array. That'll mess that one up, though not sure what's going on with the first. Good habit to avoid that bug in the future is to write out the args as a regular string and split it on the spaces in the call to spawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it works fine in a shell, so I suggest you use the `shell` option ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options)). Just make sure not to pass unsanitized user input into it. You can do it like this:

```
const args = [
    '-Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib',
    '-jar ./DynamoDBLocal.jar',
    '-inMemory'
]

const dynamodb = spawn('java', args, {cwd: './dynamodb_local', shell: true})
```

Note that with the `shell` option enabled, you'll need to add dashes to your arguments.

Comment: It works this way but I would like to know the reason why the described behaviour could be observed without `{shell: true}`

Comment: @soffyo I believe `spawn()` tries to sanitize filenames for security reasons, so using `{shell: true}` is the only way.

Comment: ok, I was confused because I have seen examples around using slashes and dots without `{shell: true}` so I didn't think it could be that but looks like It won't allow `./` or something similar